# Linear congruence mod 50

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I am revising for my exam but could not figure a way to solve the linear congruence

$$ 57x \equiv -3 \pmod{50}.$$

I have done $-3 = 50 × (-1) + 47$ but don't think i am on right track.

May someone give me a hint please.

Thanks

Comment: Hint: the coef of $x$ (which we reduce to $57\equiv 7)$ can be reduced further  by scaling the equation by $k$ such that $\,7k$ is very close to $50$. See **Gauss's Algorithm** in the linked dupes.

Answer (score 3):

$$ 57x \equiv 7x \pmod {50}$$

so we just need to find inverse of $7$ modulo $50$, and then multiply it by $-3$.

Observe that $7 \cdot 7 = 49 \equiv -1 \pmod{50}$, so $7^{-1} \equiv -7 \pmod{50}$. Therefore

$$x \equiv (-3)\cdot 7^{-1} \equiv (-3)\cdot(-7) =21 \pmod{50}$$

Comment: You pulled inverse of $7$ out of a hat - which is good for magic - but not good for math. For  *mathematical* methods see the linked dupes (and *hundreds* of others - this is a FAQ).